# High Correlation after Standardization

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting, standardization

I was working on a time series data, where there's a very low relationship between the variables(0.1 to -0.1).

After applying standardization to each of the features, half of the it starts to bear high correlation (>0.9), is this mainly because of the time series nature, or some underlying standardization effect that I'm not aware of?

Nonetheless, is it safe to say that those correlated features can be discarded?